# Having trouble Generating and Drawing a QR code onto HTML5 Canvas (using Fabric.js & jquery.qrcode)

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I am building a app based on HTML5 Canvas, and I am using the Fabric.js library, and for the most part, everything is great.

I am trying to generate, and add a Qr code to the Canvas but it does not seem to be working.

In the jQuesry.qr Code documentation it says **"If the selected element already is a canvas element, then the QR code is drawn onto it."**

So, I have generated a FabricJS canvas with a div id ="c"  ... then add dropping in the code line for the QR code:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', {
backgroundColor: 'rgb(280,280,280)'});

$('#c').qrcode({

    "size": 100,
    "color": "#3a3",
    "text": "http://larsjung.de/qrcode"
})
```

Also, once I do figure out how to add it to the Canvas, will I be able to manipulate it as I can the other fabric.js objects?

Comment: A div is not a canvas element. If fabric creates a div that _contains_ a canvas, and qrcode wants to be called _on_ a canvas element directly, then change your selector to something like `$('#c canvas')`.

Comment: Thanks CBroe, I actually just figured this out. Currently, I have it calling document.getElementsByTagName -- and I grab the IMG element that is created when I create the QR code